# How to change hotspot security type from wpa to wpa2 in kali linux

Tags: debian, gnome, kali-linux, wifi-configuration, hotspot

I'm new to kali Linux(gnome).How to change hotspot security type from wpa to wpa2, my friend trying to connect to me but unable to do so as his laptop supports only wpa2 and wpa3.
[image: screenshot]

Tried tapping on security type button but no pop appeared.

Comment: Maybe it doesn't like to change a running hotspot. Did you try changing it while the hotspot was off?

Comment: Where can I find the option when its off